# How would native speakers express “let‘s start to analysis the next problem“

Tags: american-english, spoken-english

Just like a math teacher teaches students. now the teacher is going to take students to solve another problem,

Comment: Analysis is a noun. The verb you are looking for is analyze. (And this question is better suited to English Language Learners Stackexchange)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Or **analyse** in British English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not *entirely* clear what the intention for this is.

So it seems that it is either

1. “let‘s start *the* analysis *of* the next problem“

   where "the analysis" can be a noun meaning the more general

   > [Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis) is the process of breaking a complex topic or substance into smaller parts in order to gain a better understanding of it. The technique has been applied in the study of mathematics and logic since before Aristotle (384–322 B.C.), though analysis as a formal concept is a relatively recent development.

   or in the more restricted meaning of "(mathematical) analysis"

   > [Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_analysis) is the branch of mathematics dealing with continuous functions, limits, and related theories, such as differentiation, integration, measure, infinite sequences, series, and analytic functions.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_analysis)

Alternatively, using the verb *to analyse:*

2. “let‘s start to analyse the next problem“

Given the information within the question, all variants seem to fit.

Comment: Thank you so much